# ASP.NET MVC: post-redirect-get pattern, with two overloaded action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, web-applications, post-redirect-get

Is it possible to implement post-redirect-get pattern, with two overloaded action methods (One for GET action and the other for POST action) in [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc).

In all of the MVC post-redirect-get pattern samples, I have seen three different action methods for the post-redirect-get process (corresponding to Initial Get, Post, and the Redirection Get), each having different names. Is this really required to have minimum three action methods with different names, in [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)?

For Eg: (Does the code shown below, follows Post-Redirect-Get pattern?)

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /SomeIndex/
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        SomeIndexViewModel vm = new SomeIndexViewModel(id) { myid = id };
        //Do some processing here
        return View(vm);
    }

    // POST: /SomeIndex/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SomeIndexViewModel vm)
    {
        bool validationsuccess = false;
        //validate
        if (validationsuccess)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new {id=1234 });
        else
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Where is it said you need three actions for P-R-G? You could do it with one. Strictly speaking, the "most" you can have is two: one the POST is submitted to, and the one the redirect goes to. Leaving off the page that has the initial form on it (which is your #3... but isn't necessarily being POSTed or redirected to...)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Many of the ASP.NET MVC sample code for the post-redirect-get pattern, were using three action methods. So I was doubting, whether I am missing something, in following the P-R-G pattern.

Comment: gotcha. FYI, it is easiest to keep the different tasks clear with three separate actiins, but two can work well, like in your example (one action can be done, but would sacrafice clarity/readability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think from the unit-testing perspective.

If everything was in a single action, then code would be quite difficult to test and read. I see no problems in your code what so ever.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine to me. Follows the pattern and this is how we do it in all of our projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same name for the action then you should separate which action is GET and which is POST. Also, your method signature must be different to avoid a compilation error.

Both of these "requirements" are okay in your code, so there is no problem using those actions in the PRG.

Comment: Doesn't having different parameter types mean they have different signatures? One has an int and the other has the SomeIndexViewModel.

Comment: True, that is enough to make it distinct.